# PHP / HTML Ipad (IOS) SoftKeyBoard

Tags: php, html

I have make an PHP webpage to show on Ipad / Iphone internet browser.

How to hide softkeyboard and make button that show/hide the "ABC" softkeyboard and or "123" softkeyboard?? Is that possiple from PHP or HTML??

when page is loading I want the input field autofocus and softkeyboard hide. I use a barcode scanner instead of keyboard.

And have two button next to input field as below;

Button 1 = show/hide "123" keyboard.
Button 2 = show/hide "abc" keyboard.

I have tried diffrent codes from Google search, but not working..

Anybody who can help ???

Sorry my English, not too good..... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't control those iPhone, iPad User Interface elements from HTML. Your only option is to build a native iPhone/iPad app. This needs to be written in Objective C.

Comment: Can I control those interfaces with PhoneGap? Because my C programming is very week, but I can do HTML and PHP.